# UK Bug Identification: Silver/Black Aphid?

Tags: identification, pests, bugs

I spotted these bugs circling on of my pots today, pics below. I didn't recognise them so was hoping someone could help identify these critters? I wasn't sure if they were some kind of tick, want to be cautious with kids in the garden.

[image: bug close up]
[image: bugs around pot]

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: They look like they have six legs, so not a tick. They also look like a nymph form of an insect or a true bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body shape says “[aphids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphis)” - amongst the circa 600 species of aphids are also some with stripes. I can’t give you the exact species, but I recommend you check the plant in the pot and those nearby, to catch any infestation early on. While a few are not a problem for health large plants, a colony can quickly grow (pun intended) into one.